# Should I update to ruby 2 with rails 3.2.12 on heroku?

Tags: heroku, ruby-2.0

I am running rails 3.2.12 application heroku and with ruby 1.9.3. Should I update ruby? or its not ready for production? Is it latest greatest or sticking with ruby 1.9.3 makes more sense.

Please advice.

PS: I am using unicorn as server and running approx 6-8 dynos. Also I have done other things advised by [heroku' recent blog post](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2013/4/3/routing_and_web_performance_on_heroku_a_faq)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Ruby 2 is the current stable version of Ruby.](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/)

Remember, you can fork an application (assuming your toolbelt is up to date) and test things out for yourself if you're not sure.

```
heroku fork -a your_app new_app
```

Comment: You should also update to Rails 3.2.13 which includes security fixes.